# React-router with BrowserRouter / browserHistory doesn't work on refresh

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I have the following webpack config file:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/public');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/app');

var config = {
    entry: [
        APP_DIR + '/config/routes.jsx',
        'webpack/hot/dev-server',
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080'
    ],
  output: {
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/src/client/public/'
  },
  module : {
    loaders : [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: APP_DIR,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
            presets: ['es2015']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: [ 'style', 'css', 'sass' ]
      }, 
      {
        test: /\.json$/, 
        loader: "json-loader"
     }
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

all I am trying to do is run my app on localhost, however when I hit: "http://localhost:8080/src/client/home" (as per my routes.jsx and after running webpack-dev-server)

```
import React from 'react';

import { Route, Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import Wrapper       from './../components/wrapper.jsx';
import Home          from './../components/home.jsx';
import Projects      from './../components/projects.jsx';
import SingleProject from './../components/projectContent/singleProject.jsx';
import About         from './../components/aboutUs.jsx'

ReactDOM.render((
    <Router history={browserHistory} >
        <Route path="/" component={Wrapper} >
            <Route path="home" component={Home} />
            <Route path="projects" component={Projects} />
            <Route path="projects/:id" component={SingleProject} />
            <Route path="about" component={About} />
        </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

I get

> "Cannot GET /src/client/home".

Comment: webpack-dev-server only serves the files in the build directory. Which in your case is the `public` folder inside `src/client`. Therefore `/src/client/home` is not found.

Comment: Try to visit http://localhost:8080/home

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First thing you have mentioned in your routes as the home component to have path `/home`. So you need to visit `http://localhost:8080/home`. Also if you try to access this url directly, it will give you this error since you are using `browserHistory`. If you want you can use `hashHistory` or `HashRouter` in react-router v4, in which case you will need to visit `http://localhost:8080/#/home`. If you want to continue using `browserHistory` or `BrowserRouter` as in react-router v4, then you will need to add `historyApiFallback: true`  in you webpack

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/public');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/app');

var config = {
    entry: [
        APP_DIR + '/config/routes.jsx',
        'webpack/hot/dev-server',
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080'
    ],
  output: {
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/src/client/public/'
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  module : {
    loaders : [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: APP_DIR,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
            presets: ['es2015']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: [ 'style', 'css', 'sass' ]
      }, 
      {
        test: /\.json$/, 
        loader: "json-loader"
     }
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to add this in your webpack settings:

```
devServer: {
  historyApiFallback: true,
},
```

And start your server like this:

```
webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.js
```

Because you want React-Route to handle the route instead of your server. So no matter what the url is it should goes to index.html.