# React Router not working correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, router

I am new to react and have no idea why this wouldnt be working.

My router code is here:

```
import React from 'react';  
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router'; 

import App from './components/App';  
import HomePage from './components/home/HomePage';  

export default (
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={HomePage} />
    <Route path="example" component={HomePage} />
  </Route>
);
```

So what happens with this code is:

localhost/ displays fine

localhost/example does not display

localhost/example link from the header on the homepage displays, but pressing refresh does not

Thanks for any help, I appreciate it!

here is my webpack config:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, "/client"),
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://127.0.0.0:5000/',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    'react-hot-loader/patch',
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "/client/dist"),
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [ 'babel-loader', 'react-hot-loader/webpack' ],
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './static/template.html',
      inject: 'body',
      filename: 'index.html'
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
    })
  ]
};
```

app.js snippet:

```
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'client/dist'));
app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
    publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
    hot: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    stats: {
        colors: true
    }
}));
```

I am using `localhost:5000` . The question linked did not fix my problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React webpack-dev-server cannot get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40332753/react-webpack-dev-server-cannot-get)

Comment: See the duplicate question. I am sure that will solve your problem

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri that did not work, any other advice? I have edited

Comment: Are you serving your React Application from the server, in that case, can you try this `https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-history-api-fallback`

Answer (score -1):

FYI, Starting in version 4.0, React Router no longer uses the IndexRoute.

Also for your path, change `"example"` to `"/example"`

Comment: OP did not say he uses React router v4, also if `localhost/example link from the header on the homepage displays, but pressing refresh does not` line shows that he is not using v4 otherwise it wouldn'nt have worked at all