# React Router wildcard not being matched

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to get my app to just direct to a component when a user clicks on a link the app provides (think email verification).
So far this is all I'm getting when I click on the link:

```
Cannot GET /verify/eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1Ni[...]
```

This is my router code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory} from 'react-router';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import App from './App';
import Log_In from './components/Log_In/Log_In';
import Sign_Up from './components/Sign_Up/Sign_Up';
import SignUp_Redirect from './components/Sign_Up/SignUp_Redirect';
import Verify from './components/Sign_Up/Verify';
import Sign_Out from './components/Sign_Out/Sign_Out';
import Require_Auth from './components/authentication/require_auth';

export default (
 <Route path="/" component={App}>
  <IndexRoute component={Log_In}/>
  <Route path="signin" component={Log_In}/>
  <Route path="signup" component={Sign_Up}/>
  <Route path="signup_redirect" component={Require_Auth(SignUp_Redirect)}/>
  <Route path="verify/:token" component={Verify}/>
  <Route path="signout" component={Require_Auth(Sign_Out)}/>
 </Route>
);
```

The component Verify just generates some simple HTML, nothing fancy. I tried putting path="verify/*" but that also doesn't work. All the examples and docs I could find shows the above code for a wildcard. Not sure what else I'm supposed to use.
React-router on my project is v. 2.0.1 so I don't know if that has any bearing on this.
Any help is appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: Problem fixed. Changed browserHistory to hashHistory.

Comment: try `path="/verify/:token"`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri that doesn't change the behavior :(

Comment: do you navigate using Link or refresh the page with the above url

Comment: Refreshing the page with it, since a user is supposed to click on the link from their email.
The full path for the link right now is
    http://localhost:8080/verify/[tokenhere}

Comment: cool then the problem is related to the history object that is browserHistory that is used. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40332753/react-webpack-dev-server-cannot-get/40338808#40338808

Comment: Thank you! I changed it to hashHistory and it's working now.

Comment: You need not change to hashHistory, rather if you are using webpack, use `historyApiFallback: true` as mentioned in the duplicate question

Comment: I did have historyApiFallback set to true in my webpack config file, but I still got that error. Only changing it to hashHistory works for me.