# React Router not working: GET http://localhost:8080/test 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, http-status-code-404

I have the following code:

```
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
       <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
       <Route path="/test" component={Component} />
       <Route component={NotFoundComponent} />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

Whenever I visit `/`, I see `App`. So that works fine. However, everything else does not:

When I try to go to `/test/` I get `Cannot get /test` and in the console: `GET http://localhost:8080/test 404 (Not Found)`. When I go to any other page, I don't get the `NotFoundComponent`, but simply the same as just described.

I am using React Router v4, I don't have Redux installed, everything is pretty basic, not using anything else as of now.

Comment: Its probably the same issue, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40332753/react-webpack-dev-server-cannot-get/40338808#40338808

Comment: I don't understand how this is related to my problem?

Comment: I felt it because, from what I suppose you were trying to manually enter the url `http://localhost:8080/test` in the browser and since you are using BrowserRouter you would need to use historyApiFallback: true . Correct me if my assumption was wrong

Comment: Sorry, I did not get that! Yup, you were right, that was it! If you would submit this as an answer, I would choose it of course! :) Thanks a lot!