# Error 404 in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

i am fairly new to react and i'm trying to pick it up slowly , anyways this is the error that i run to: **GET http://localhost:8888/User 404 (Not Found)**, this is my code :

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Header } from "./Header";
import { User } from "./User";

    class App extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <BrowserRouter>
            <div>
              <Route path={"/User"} component={User} />
              <Route path={"/Header"} component={Header} />
            </div>
          </BrowserRouter>
        );
      }
    }
    render(<App />, window.document.getElementById("Root"));
```

Do i have a directory problem? But all the components are in the same folder, any help is greatly appreciated , thank you.

Comment: when using browserRouter and directly entering a link the URL you need to configure your webpack as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40332753/react-webpack-dev-server-with-react-router-gives-page-not-found-error/40338808#40338808. Or else use HashRouter and enter the route as `http://localhost:8888/#/User`

Comment: Do you see anything in console?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri thank you so much that did the trick for me, have a good day mate.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote questions and answers on stackoverflow that help you

Answer (score 0):

if you are using webpack's dev-server you should add to the config this line:

```
historyApiFallback: true
```

https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#api