# react-router-dom direct access to child path

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have my main route in my main component set like that

```
<Main>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/login" component={ LoginPage }/>
        <PrivateRoute path="/" component={ PrivatePages }/>
    </Switch>
</Main>
```

and inside `PrivatePages` the routes are set like this

```
<div>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/users/:id" component={ UsersPage }/>
    </Switch>
</div>
```

when I'm accessing it like http://localhost:3000/users I see the right page (the UsersPage component) and when I click on a user it transfer to http://localhost:3000/users/someUserId (I'm doing it by using `<Link>`) and it works perfectly fine .. but when I refresh or trying to rich directly to a specific user's page I get a blank page which tries to load `http://localhost:3000/users/main.js` (I have no idea why it tried to load this file) I guess it's something from react-router-dom I tried to google it but I didn't find anything relevant ... can't put my finger hand on what I'm missing exactly.

thanks.

Comment: I guess you are using browserRouter and maybe this answer will help you solve it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40332753/react-webpack-dev-server-with-react-router-gives-page-not-found-error/40338808#40338808

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri thanks for the reply, I do have the `historyApiFallback`in the webpack config set to true. but I don't think it's the same issues as he couldn't load a page and for me it aims to load `/users/main.js` which could be fine if it would load `index.js`

Comment: So it redirects you to `http://localhost:3000/users/main.js`? If you use `webpack-dev-server` please show your webpack config.

Comment: @GProst, it doesnt redirect at all its showing a blank page that tried to load
`http://localhost:3000/users/main.js` when im trying to rich directly a specific user `http://localhost:3000/users/someUserId`

here is the dev config which in the `webpack.config.babel`

https://pastebin.com/RWAb2yCy

Comment: Thx, can you also show exact server response for `http://localhost:3000/users/someUserId`? Plus, are there any errors in console?

Comment: @GProst thanks for the reply, console showing `GET http://localhost:3000/users/main.js 404 (Not Found)`
and server res for specific user is here https://pastebin.com/Nq87DGbN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, your page is blank because it can't download your `main.js` file which initializes your React app.

Corresponding to your dev server output-public-path (which is `/` by default) you should be able to download `main.js` with the following URL: `http://localhost:3000/main.js`, but you have `http://localhost:3000/users/main.js`. This is because you specified `src='main.js'` for `<script>` in your html file, which is a relative path. Server takes current URL path (`http://localhost:3000/users/`) and concatenates it with `main.js`. And we have `http://localhost:3000/users/main.js`.

You just need to set your `<script>` `src` attribute with an absolute path:
 `src="/main.js"`.

Comment: I decided eventually to use `HtmlWebpackPlugin` and I found this which solved the issue - https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/156 - but thanks a lot for showing me the point of the problem :)