# React Route URL

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm new with React. I'm using `react-router-dom`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Switch, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './components/home';
import Login from './components/login';

class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="app">
          <Link to='/'>Home</Link>
          <Link to='/login'>Login</Link>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
            <Route path='/login' component={Login}/>
          </Switch>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

I'm using this code everything work fine, but when I go to `localhost:8080/login` directly via de url I get a error `Cannot GET /login` but it goes well through a link `<Link to='/login'>Login</Link>`.

how can I fix it?

Comment: Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40332753/react-changing-url-with-react-router-and-webpack-gives-page-not-found-error/40338808#40338808

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri almost, but i found a next problem, how can I remove the `#` from `http://localhost:8080/#/home`

Comment: Instead of using HashRouter, you would use BrowserRouter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is often a tricky thing I deal with in regards to navigating with react.

By navigating directly to /login your React App hasn't actually rendered the highest parent or root and thus there really isn't a login component to find and render. Here's what I do when working with logins and home

```
<Route exact path="/" component={() => this.props.auth ? <DashboardContainer/> : <Redirect to="/" />}/>
```

This says if there isn't any auth (or local storage, or cookies, or whatever you're using to log them in) redirect back home or to / so they can click /login.

Basically you need your highest level component to mount virtually before you can do anything else. You can also make /login your landing page, so in this case merge / and /login. But the above example is modularized and dynamic.