# React-Router-Dom path's params

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I was trying to include a dynamic link using react-router-dom paths params e.g. (paths:"/link/:params"). But somehow any requests to such links returns a 404 error. Note the third route.

```
    import React from 'react'
    import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
    const EditExpensePage = (props) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <p>EditExpense Page with id of {props.match.params.id}</p>
        </div>
      )
    }

const AppRouter = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>

    <div>
      <Header/>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={DashboardPage} exact={true}/>
        <Route path="/create/" component={AddExpensePage}/>
        <Route path="/edit/:id" component={EditExpensePage}/>
        <Route path="/help" component={HelpPage}/>
        <Route component={NotFoundPage}/>
    </Switch>
    </div>

  </BrowserRouter>
)

export default AppRouter;
```

When I tried to visit the link eg.(localhost:8080/edit/43), i got a blank page with a log in the console which came from my bundled js file:

```
GET http://localhost:8081/edit/scripts/app.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [React-router with BrowserRouter / browserHistory doesn't work on Reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40332753/react-router-with-browserrouter-browserhistory-doesnt-work-on-reload/40338808#40338808)

Comment: You can try to set 'baseName' attribute to `BrowserRouter` - https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/BrowserRouter.md#basename-string

Comment: I tried those solutions but the outcome is still the same. Does this have to do with the browserHistory?