# React Router Route page breaks when refreshed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router, react-redux

I am having an issue with React Router route.
When I click on the component, it takes me to the correct Route and renders the correct component. However, whenever I refresh the page, it breaks and nothing shows up on the page.

Below is my main.js:

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter, BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, HashHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import ServicePage from './ServicePage';
import ProductPage from './ProductPage';
import MechanicalProductPage from './MechanicalProductPage';
import Body from './Body';


class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <main>
        <BrowserRouter history={HashHistory}>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Body} />
            <Route exact path='/services' component={ServicePage} />
            <Route exact path='/products' component={ProductPage} />
            <Route exact path='/products/mechanical-products' exact component={MechanicalProductPage} />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </main>
    )
  }
}

export default Main;
```

I having a issue with :

```
<Route exact path='/products/mechanical-products' exact component={MechanicalProductPage} />
```

Here is my ProductPage.js:

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import Card, { CardActions, CardContent, CardMedia } from 'material-ui/Card';
import Button from 'material-ui/Button';
import Typography from 'material-ui/Typography';
require('../../scss/style.scss');

export default class ProductPage extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="product-page">
        <h1>Products</h1>
        <div className="section-header-line"></div>

        <div className="all-products-container">
          <div className="row-fluid span12">
            <div className="span4" style={{marginLeft: '180px'}}>
              <Link to="/products/mechanical-products" className="card-link">
                <Card className="service-card">
                  <CardMedia
                    className="service-card-image"
                    image="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/c19c76_22d8ec47d1484b09a9c333e4141a12a0.jpg/v1/fill/w_600,h_454,al_c,q_80,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/c19c76_22d8ec47d1484b09a9c333e4141a12a0.webp"
                    title="Contemplative Reptile"
                    style={{height: '200'}}
                  />
                  <CardContent>
                    <Typography type="headline" component="h2">
                      Mechanical
                    </Typography>
                  </CardContent>
                </Card>
              </Link>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

As you can see, "card" component has been wrapped with "Link" which takes you to "/products/mechanical-products".

Below is my MechanicalProductPage.js

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// require('../../scss/servicePage.scss');
require('../../scss/style.scss');


class MechanicalProductPage extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="service-page">
        <h1>Mechanical Products</h1>
        <div className="section-header-line"></div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default MechanicalProductPage;
```

Here is my webpack.config.js :

```html
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        contentBase: './src',
        // contentBase: './',
        port: 3000,
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    entry: './dev/js/index.js',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                // loader: ['babel?retainLines=true'],
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    cacheDirectory: true,
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
                    plugins: ['transform-class-properties']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'
            }
        ],
    },
    output: {
        path: 'src',
        filename: 'js/bundle.min.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin()
    ]
};
```

When the "card component" in the ProductPage.js has been clicked, it takes me to "/products/mechanical-products" page and correct component being rendered. However, when I refresh the page after the component has been rendered, the page breaks and nothing pops up. I don't get any error in the console.

Could anyone please help me with this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React-router with BrowserRouter / browserHistory doesn't work on Reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40332753/react-router-with-browserrouter-browserhistory-doesnt-work-on-reload/40338808#40338808)

Comment: It makes sense that page reload in browser breaks the content rendering because issued GET localhost:3000/your-url doesn't have nothing to return. React library didn't load. React library will load only when you visit root of your app GET localhost:3000 where index.js will be served and inside of it React Router initialisation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I fixed a similar issue:

Apparently it has something to do with rehydration process of react: this article was a guide to understanging the siolution: [https://www.joshwcomeau.com/react/the-perils-of-rehydration/#:~:text=to%20this%20heading-,The%20solution,-To%20avoid%20issues](https://www.joshwcomeau.com/react/the-perils-of-rehydration/#:%7E:text=to%20this%20heading-,The%20solution,-To%20avoid%20issues)

```
const ComponentToBeRenderedOnAnotherRoutePath = () => {
  const [hasMounted, setHasMounted] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setHasMounted(true);
  }, []);

  if (!hasMounted) {
    return null;
  } else
    return <>your code</>
};

export default ComponentToBeRenderedOnAnotherRoutePath;
```