# React Router Route Path Params won't work

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I was trying to reach the param react router gives you while using it

so I wanted to change my path to

```
<Route path="/edit/:id" component={EditExpansePage} />
```

but actually, it never works, it keeps getting errors or not found

Comment: how are you trying to access it?

Comment: through the webpack dev server local host: http://localhost:8080/edit/99 @RishikeshDhokare

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40332753/react-router-with-browserrouter-browserhistory-doesnt-work-on-refresh/40338808#40338808, it might be the issue

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I actually have it on just as him and it doesnt really change it

Comment: Can you add more information on your Routes, also what sort of errors do you get

Comment: its a very simple routes like <Route path="/" component={ExpenseDashboardPage} exact={true} /> and it works just fine but when i try to add <Route path="/edit/:id" component={EditExpensePage} /> it doesn't really work even though it should work according to even their gihub

Comment: GET http://localhost:8080/edit/bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED
99:10 GET http://localhost:8080/edit/bundle.js 404 (Not Found) 
these are the errors i get

Comment: What is your Link's look like?  Are you sure it can reach that EditExpansePage and that it is properly defined and imported?

Comment: @donlaur hey, thanks for asking, apparently it was something to do with this html tag <base href="/" /> not rly a syntax error