# dynamic url path in reactjs application not working

Tags: reactjs

Hi I want all my dynamic urls to hit same component TournamentDetail. Urls will be like http://localhost/tournament-detail/name1/102 or http://localhost/tournament-detail/name2/103 etc. I have defined route as

```
<Route path="/tournament-detail/:name/:id" component={TournamentDetail}/>
```

But it is not working. Can someone tell me what is wrong ?

Comment: What do you mean by not working

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [/react-router-with-browserrouter-browserhistory-doesnt-work-on-refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40332753/react-router-with-browserrouter-browserhistory-doesnt-work-on-refresh/40338808#40338808)

Comment: @hitesh Could you please add more code? I've run into same problems and I think what you are asking is similar to them. Need to be sure.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I get a blank page when hit url like localhost/tournament-detail/name/1 . I have posted the error in my response below

Comment: @AjayGupta added source code

Answer (score 0):

If I hit url like localhost/tournament-detail/name/1 I get following error and page does not render

Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8081/tournament-detail/name/node_modules/react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
1:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8081/tournament-detail/name/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
index.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
universalModuleDefinition:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addons' of undefined
    at universalModuleDefinition:9
    at universalModuleDefinition:9
index.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
1:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8081/tournament-detail/name/index.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
1:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8081/tournament-detail/name/node_modules/react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
1:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8081/tournament-detail/name/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

reactjs component file is as follows :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from './Header.js';
import Footer from './Footer.js';
import Notification from './Notification.js';
import Menu from './Menu.js';
import {Route,Switch} from "react-router-dom";
import TournamentListPage from './TournamentListPage.js';
import IndexPage from "./IndexPage.js";
import Ladder from "./Ladder.js";
import Auth from './Auth.js';
import Fyp from './Fyp.js';
import Register from './Register.js';
import ValidateEmail from './ValidateEmail.js';
import ResetPassword from './ResetPassword.js';
import TournamentDetail from './TournamentDetail.js';

    export default class Home extends Component{

      render(){
        return(
          <div>
              <Notification/>
              <Header/>
              <Menu/>
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={IndexPage}/>
                <Route path="/tournaments" component={TournamentListPage}/>
                <Route path="/players-ladder" component={Ladder}/>
                <Route path="/login" component={Auth}/>
                <Route path="/fyp" component={Fyp}/>
                <Route path="/register" component={Register}/>
                <Route path="/validateemail" component={ValidateEmail}/>
                <Route path="/reset-password" component={ResetPassword}/>
                <Route path="/tournament-detail/:name/:id" component={TournamentDetail}/>
              </Switch>
              <Footer/>
          </div>
        );
      }

    }
```