# React router v4 - How to combine dynamic and optional routes?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, webpack-dev-server, react-router-v4

I need a 2 level routing at root level where the both routes are dynamic and second route is optional. I tried to set up my path as below but got an error.

Here is my route configuration:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path='/' component={CompOne} />
  <Route path='/:name/:id?'
      render={(routeProps) => (
          <Details {...routeProps} />
      )}
  />
</Switch>
```

Here I have name as one dynamic params, id is the second but its optional.

In browser when I load: `localhost:8080/vishal` or `localhost:8080/vishal/123`, it should load the same component. Inside component I check if the url has the id. However, I get 404 error:

https://localhost:8080/vishal/123/bootstrap.min.css

https://localhost:8080/vishal/123/bundle.js

*If I wrap optional param in (), I get below error:*

`<Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={CompOne} />
      <Route path='/:name(/:id)?'
          render={(routeProps) => (
              <Details {...routeProps} />
          )}
      />
</Switch>`

I get 404 that bundle.js not found in case I pass in id as well. hence /vishal works, /vishal/123 gives error 404 - `localhost:8080/vishal/bundle.js`.

Comment: Most probably your issue is related to [react-router-with-browserrouter-browserhistory-doesnt-work-on-refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40332753/react-router-with-browserrouter-browserhistory-doesnt-work-on-refresh/40338808#40338808) also your optional route path must ideally be `path='/:name(/:id)?'`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Tried that, in that case my routeProps.match.params is empty. Hence my app fails.

Comment: That is likely to happen since you don't pass the params, you need to provide a conditional check before using `match.params.id`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I have already done that. I get 404 that bundle.js not found in case I pass in id as well. hence /vishal works, /vishal/123 gives error

Comment: `<Route path='/:name(/:id)'` is incorrect, you need to write `<Route path='/:name(/:id)?'`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri that was a typo, sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169138/discussion-between-shubham-khatri-and-vishal-gulati).

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I cant access the chat at my network Sorry for that. Could you please share in case you can make out anything from my error.

Comment: Can you let me know if you `<Route path='/:name/:id'` works with path `/vishal/123`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri with the above change I get [WDS] Disconnected! for route /vishal and same 404 for bundle.js for /vishal/123

Comment: It seems there is an issue with how you are rendering your component, because it doesn't seem to resolve bootstrap.min.css and bundle.js

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={CompOne} />
      <Route path='/:name/:id?'
          render={(routeProps) => {
              console.log(routeProps);
              return <Details {...routeProps} />;
          }}
      />
    </Switch>
```

Comment: in the render, add in a console.log(routeProps) and what does it log? the name and id are params, so routeProps might be an object containing `params`.  without having the project it's hard for me to test it out myself. sry.

Comment: Tried that, in that case my routeProps.match.params is empty. Hence my app fails.

Comment: I get 404 that bundle.js not found in case I pass in id as well. hence /vishal works, /vishal/123 gives error  404 - https://localhost:8080/vishal/bundle.js

Comment: I edited the above code section.  With v4, optional Params are declared with a ?.  Copy and paste that code and let me know what logs to the console when you run it.