# Cannot connect page by address directly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am making my own blog now and using react with react-router-dom.
When I type url except '/' in address bar directly, I get Cannot GET /url error in chrome.
But localhost:8000/ is working properly.
ex) localhost:8000/favorite ==> Cannot GET /favorite

And clicking header and redirect is working. Only typing in address bar is not working.

My codes structure simplified below.

index.js

```
const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
ReactDOM.render(
   <BrowserRouter>
       <App />
   </BrowserRouter>
, 
rootElement);
```

App.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render(){

        return (
            <div>
                <Header/>
                <Main></Main>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Main.js

```
const Main = () => (
  <main>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={HomeContainer}/>
      <Route path='/post' component={Post}/>
      <Route path='/favorite' component={Favorite}/>
      <Route path='/setting' component={Setting}/>
    </Switch>
  </main>
)

export default Main
```

header.js

```
<div>
    <Menu.Item><Link to='/'><Icon onClick={this.clickMenu} name='home' data- name='home' size="large"/></Link></Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item><Link to='/post'><Icon onClick={this.clickMenu} name='list'data-name='list' size="large"/></Link></Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item><Link to='/favorite'><Icon onClick={this.clickMenu} name='favorite' data-name='favorite' size="large"/></Link></Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item><Link to='/setting'><Icon onClick={this.clickMenu} name='settings' data-name='settings'size="large"/>/Link></Menu.Item>

</div>
```

Comment: Are you running `webpack` if so configure webpack with [`historyApiFallback`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-historyapifallback)

Comment: If you are using webpack-dev-server, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40332753/react-router-with-browserrouter-browserhistory-doesnt-work-on-refresh/40338808#40338808