# React router structure for dashboard component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Hi i am new developer in ReactJS. I have a problem and want to learn how to make routing for dashboard. My root component is App component and it calls only dashboards of my pages. But I want to call different components inside of dashboard such as Login , Register etc. When I use "Link" in anywhere, How can I do this ? Could you help me at this issue?

index.tsx for BrowserRouter

```
import {BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";

const app =<App /> ;
const container = (
    <>
    <BrowserRouter>
       {app} 
    </BrowserRouter>
    </>
);
```

my router App.tsx component:

```
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import LoginDash from "../containers/login/LoginDash"

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/Login" exact component={LoginDash}></Route>
          <Route path="/" exact component={LoginDash}></Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

My dashboard LoginDash.tsx:

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route,Switch} from "react-router-dom"
import LoginPart from "../../components/login/left/LoginPart";
import RegisterPart from "../../components/login/left/RegisterPart";
import AnitamionPart from '../../components/login/right/AnimationPart';

export const Login = () => {
  return (
    <div className="login-container">
      <div className="row login-row" >
        <div className="login-left-part" >
          <Router>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path = "/Login" component={LoginPart}></Route>
              <Route exact path = "/Register" component={RegisterPart}></Route>
            </Switch>
          </Router>
        </div>
        <div className=" login-right-part" >
          <AnitamionPart></AnitamionPart>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 2):

**First of all**, you only need to use one instance of `BrowserRouter` in your App, Since you already wrap `App` component with `BrowserRouter` that would be enough

**Secondly**, if you specify exact attribute on Routes, no nested Routes will ever match. Make sure you don't use Route with exact prop if the component has any nested Route defined

**Lastly**, you only need to render LoginDash on `/` route, `/Login` handling can be done separately as a nested Route

Update your individual components like below

```
import {BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";

// Do not render app as a constant separetely, 

const container = (
    <>
    <BrowserRouter>
       <App />  
    </BrowserRouter>
    </>
);
```

---

```
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import LoginDash from "../containers/login/LoginDash"

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
         <Route path="/" component={LoginDash}></Route>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

---

```
export const Login = () => {
  return (
    <div className="login-container">
      <div className="row login-row" >
        <div className="login-left-part" >
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path = "/Login" component={LoginPart}></Route>
              <Route exact path = "/Register" component={RegisterPart}></Route>
            </Switch>
        </div>
        <div className=" login-right-part" >
          <AnitamionPart></AnitamionPart>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login;
```

**[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-herschel-mm57l?file=/src/index.js)**

Comment: When I write to "/Login or /Register" , it return empty page. There is a problem. Actualy ı understand your description but code does not work.

Comment: I saw your demo. It works correctly there. But I am facing empty screen when I write something. what can be problem do you think atnoher from this ?

Comment: How are you rendering `const container = (
    <>
    <BrowserRouter>
       <App />  
    </BrowserRouter>
    </>
);` Also did you remove the usage of Router from  `LoginDash`

Comment: I changed everything what you want for example like  `this.ReactDOM.render(<
    LoginContextProvider>
    <Provider>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
</LoginContextProvider>, documentContainer);`
Yes. I removed to Router. could the reason be about webpack?

Comment: how do you change the route, do you change the url directly or use link. If you change url directly, you need to configure webpack to use historyApiFallback. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40332753/react-router-with-browserrouter-browserhistory-doesnt-work-on-refresh/40338808#40338808 for more details