# Reactjs - changing url using react router but the component does not change

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to render a navbar with links to login and signup pages, but whenever i click them the url changes as i wanted them to but the respective components are not rendered. Here's my code:

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import NavBar from './components/NavBar/NavBar';
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Route,withRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import Login from './components/Login';
import SignUp from './components/SignUp';
import Landing from './components/Landing';


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">

          <NavBar />
          <Route exact path="/" component={withRouter(Landing)} />
          <div className="container">
            <Route exact path="/login" component={withRouter(Login)} />
            <Route exact path="/signup" component={withRouter(SignUp)} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

**NavBar.js**

```
import React,{Component} from "react";
import {BrowserRouter as Router,withRouter,Link} from "react-router-dom";
import './NavBar.css'



class NavBar extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
            <header className='navbar'>
                <nav className='navbar_navigation'>
                    <div />
                    <div className='navbar_logo'>
                        <Link to='/'>Home</Link>
                    </div>
                    <div className='navbar_nav-items'>
                        <ul>
                            <li><Link to="/signup" className="nav-link">Sign up</Link></li>
                            <li><Link to="/login" className="nav-link">Log In</Link></li>
                            <li><Link to="/guest-env" className="nav-link">Continue as guest</Link></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </header>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(NavBar);
```

The Landing, Login and Signup are basically components that just render text in h2 for now since I want to see if they render fine. Also when i go to the respective urls directly: /login or /signup, I don't see any change and the navbar is the only thing rendered in those urls as well.
I have tried adding switch as well but nothing seems to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that Navbar component is using a Router on its own and hence the Link components are not able to communicate to the outer `Router` component which renders the Routes. Make sure you use only one Router component instance.

You Navbar component doesn't need a `Router` instance

```
class NavBar extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <header className='navbar'>
                <nav className='navbar_navigation'>
                    <div />
                    <div className='navbar_logo'>
                        <Link to='/'>Home</Link>
                    </div>
                    <div className='navbar_nav-items'>
                        <ul>
                            <li><Link to="/signup" className="nav-link">Sign up</Link></li>
                            <li><Link to="/login" className="nav-link">Log In</Link></li>
                            <li><Link to="/guest-env" className="nav-link">Continue as guest</Link></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </header>
        );
    }
}
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-hugle-t3uht?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: I removed Router from navbar and i am still getting the same problem. Even if i type the url localhost:3000/login or /signup i am not getting their respective components(which is just h2 text). Is there something else I am doing wrong?

Comment: which version react-router are you using

Comment: I'm using react-router-dom version 5.1.2

Comment: I added a working demo. The navigation by changing url will need you to configure historyApiFallback in webpack. PLease look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40332753/react-router-with-browserrouter-browserhistory-doesnt-work-on-refresh/40338808#40338808

Comment: I followed your code and i am getting the same output as yours when i remove my navbar.css file import. I have added that to the demo, could you take a look and let me know what my css file is doing wrong?

Comment: @VishwaShankar, you need to share the updated demo.

Comment: my bad updated demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-ganguly-0r58p

Comment: I realized that the position of the navbar was fixed which is causing the text to not show up. Thank you for taking the time to create a sandbox!

Comment: Yeah I was just about to say that. You navbar hid the content behind it

Answer (score -1):

If you want to render just one component based on route, you need to use the `Switch` component from react-router:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom"


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <NavBar />
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/">
                <Page 1 />
              </Route>
              <Route exact path="/login">
                <Page 2 />
              </Route>
              ... etc
            </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```